# Converting all elements to strings in a list of list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of list which has both integers and strings inside it as their values. Now I want to convert all the values to string.

My list of list looks like : (say `final_rule`)

```
[[3, '*', 1, 4, 1], [1, 2, '*', 2, 1], ['*', '*', 3, 4, 1], [2, 2, '*', 2, 1]]
```

And I am trying to produce an output as:

```
[['3', '*', '1', '4', '1'], ['1', '2', '*', '2', '1'], ['*', '*', '3', '4', '1'], ['2', '2', '*', '2', '1']]
```

I am trying the below code:

```
new_list=[]
for list_ in final_rule:
    #print("list_:",list_)
    [str(i) for i in list_]
    new_list.append(i)
return new_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [[3, '*', 1, 4, 1], [1, 2, '*', 2, 1], ['*', '*', 3, 4, 1], [2, 2, '*', 2, 1]]

list(list(map(str, terms)) for terms in lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int_list = [[3, '*', 1, 4, 1], [1, 2, '*', 2, 1], ['*', '*', 3, 4, 1], [2, 2, '*', 2, 1]]

# you can use nested loop like following.
str_list = [[str(i) for i in j] for j in int_list]
```

output

```
[['3', '*', '1', '4', '1'],
 ['1', '2', '*', '2', '1'],
 ['*', '*', '3', '4', '1'],
 ['2', '2', '*', '2', '1']]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little?

Comment: Dev that is just another way of writing nested loops in a single line.

Comment: What is data in the code?

Comment: @Dev edited, that was int_list. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You are close! Comprehension is fine, but it does not modify list in place, it creates a new one. So you need to `append` new list:

```py
def stringify(final_rule):
    new_list=[]
    for list_ in final_rule:
        #print("list_:",list_)
        strings = [str(i) for i in list_]
        new_list.append(strings)
    return new_list
```

But you can achieve the same with a single comprehension:

```py
def stringify(final_value):
    return [[str(i) for i in inner] for inner in final_value]
```

Alternatively, inner list may be constructed with `list(map(str, inner))`, but I'm not sure what will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it using the map() and List Comprehension.

```
a = [[3, '*', 1, 4, 1], [1, 2, '*', 2, 1], ['*', '*', 3, 4, 1], [2, 2, '*', 2, 1]]
result = [list(map(str,x)) for x in a]
```